# $dayOfMonth aggregation in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in mongodb having structure as :

```
    {
"_id": {
    "$oid": "565272dbe4b00dbeb0fe76b9"
},
"ObjectTemp": 20.706992938189444,
"AmbientTemp": 26.78125,
"timeStamp": "2015-11-23T01:58:52.084Z"
      }
```

I want to apply an aggregate function to get count of docs having value of "ObjectTemp" greater than 10 and less than 10 in 1 day. I used below query to get the result"

```
     db.temp.aggregate([{
     $project: {
      day :{$dayOfMonth: { $substr: [ "$timeStamp", 0, 10] }},
    lessThan10: { $cond: [ { $lt: ["$ObjectTemp", 10 ] }, 1, 0]},
     moreThan10: {$cond:[ {  $gt: [ "$ObjectTemp", 10 ] }, 1, 0]}}
               },

       {
      $group: { 
     _id : "$day",
      countSmaller: { $sum: "$lessThan10" },
     countBigger: { $sum: "$moreThan10" }
      }
      },{$sort: { _id : -1 }}])
```

On executing I am getting error:

```
             assert: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type String to Date",
    "code" : 16006,
    "ok" : 0
    } : aggregate failed
      Error: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type String to Date",
    "code" : 16006,
    "ok" : 0
      } : aggregate failed
at Error (<anonymous>)
at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
at (shell):1:9
    2015-11-24T10:46:38.770-0800 E QUERY    Error: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type String to Date",
    "code" : 16006,
    "ok" : 0
     } : aggregate failed
at Error (<anonymous>)
at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
at (shell):1:9 at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13
```

Any suggestion where am getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo is telling you right in the error message - its seeing a string and not a date.

`"2015-11-23T01:58:52.084Z"` is a string. If it was a date it would be `ISODate("2015-11-23T01:58:52.084Z")`.

You need to change your data to date format.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question

Comment: @user3100115 I thought it was pretty clear, but I updated to make it clearer

Comment: What about showing how this can be done? you answer  should be a comment.

Comment: @user3100115 Doing that would be highly dependent on the OP's use cases and requires more information than the OP has provided. It is outside the scope of this question. You're welcome to downvote if you do not like my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96080/discussion-between-user3100115-and-david-grinberg).

Answer (score 0):

To use `$dayOfMonth` you'll need timestamp to be of type `Date`. One thing that you can do is change to the following code to convert the string to date.

```
db.testing.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            day :{$dayOfMonth: new Date("$timeStamp")},
            lessThan10: { $cond: [ { $lt: ["$ObjectTemp", 10 ] }, 1, 0]},
            moreThan10: {$cond:[ {  $gt: [ "$ObjectTemp", 10 ] }, 1, 0]}}
        },
    {
        $group: { 
            _id : "$day",
            countSmaller: { $sum: "$lessThan10" },
            countBigger: { $sum: "$moreThan10" }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { _id : -1 }
    }
])
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : 23, "countSmaller" : 0, "countBigger" : 1 }
```

**EDIT**: It seems to work. Maybe you didn't check it correctly. I have updated the answer with the full command and the output.

Comment: @user3100115 I have updated the answer. Have a look.

Answer (score -2):

yes I know that. I figured out the solution. As this is string so I cannot use $dayofMonth attribute. So I substring the date directly. Here is my new query which worked :

```
                     db.temp.aggregate([{
                  $project: {
               day :{ $substr: [ "$timeStamp", 8, 2] },
               lessThan10: { $cond: [ { $lt: ["$ObjectTemp", 10 ] }, 1, 0]},
               moreThan10: {$cond:[ {  $gt: [ "$ObjectTemp", 10 ] }, 1, 0]}}
                 },

                 {
                    $group: { 
                  _id : "$day",
                   countSmaller: { $sum: "$lessThan10" },
                    countBigger: { $sum: "$moreThan10" }
                       }
                    },{$sort: { _id : -1 }}])`
```

Comment: Its not a good idea. Don't treat your dates as strings. Either change them or cast them.

Comment: This is wrong you need to update your document and convert your ISO string to Date.

Comment: @David i have so many records already in my database, While inserting I am using new Date() function, but I am using ajax Post call to insert in mongoDB.   

$.ajax( { url: "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/my-db/collections/my-coll?apiKey=myAPIKey",
    data: JSON.stringify( [ { "x" : 1 }, { "x" : 2 }, { "timeStamp" : new Date() } ] ),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json" } );

So it stringify my date.
How can I cast it or change it while inserting.

Comment: If you want to know how to have a correct Date Object created via the MongoLab http API then you can [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) or even read their documentation. Personally I don't see why you would bother. If you are running this aggregate code against your MongoLab database then you have a native connection, so if baffles why you are even using the http API in the first place, since like all "pre-rolled" CRUD interfaces, it's very limitted. Better to implement your own CRUD layer in your application.